# Function becomes undefined after first trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, scope

I have a block of code like so:

```
function doSomething() {
    someVar.on("event_name", function() {
        $('#elementId').click(function(e) {
            doSomething();
        });
    });
}

// and on document ready
 $(function () {
    $('#anotherElemId').click(function () {
        doSomething();
    });
});
```

The problem that I'm encountering is that when I call `doSomething()` from `anotherElemId` click event(that is binded on document ready) it works as expected, but calling it recursively from `elementId` click doesn't work.

Any ideas? Thinking is something trivial that I'm missing.

Comment: `('#elementId').click(function(e) {` need to be `$('#elementId').click(function(e) {`

Comment: Also running doSomething will show return value in firebug, as you are returning nothing it should show undefined, try return 'didSomethig';

Comment: Are you sure you're not using the `doSomething` name for something else?

Comment: Why are you recursively adding an event handler to the same element? That does not look right... in any case, you should provide a more complete example as http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. I'm sure there is more going on than what you showed.

Comment: @GabrielSantos typo in my question. Fixed.

Comment: @sabithpocker true, rephrased, looks like scope issue.

Comment: @Felix I'm also removing it at some point to change it to something else...is a toogle button that connects and disconnects from a chat. Do something set's up the whole connection params. Writing a more complete example now.

Comment: This the part of the javascript code that I'm using. http://pastebin.com/VJbvYtn9

Answer (score 0):

Is someVar an actual jQuery reference to a dom element? (e.g. $('#someitem'))

The second problem is you cant put a .click event inside a function that you would like to instantiate later on. If you are trying to only allow #elementId to have a click event AFTER some previous event, try testing if a tester variable is true:

```
var activated = false;

$(function () {
    $('#anotherElemId').click(function () {
        activated = true;
    });

    $('#secondElemId').on("event_name", function() {
        if (activated) {
            // code that happens only after #anotherElemId was clicked.
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: someVar is not a dom element. See my comment with link to pastebin. The click event was getting triggered, as my console log statements were being executed. I've changed it in the mean time to have 2 links separate connect/disconnect ids and events attached outside the setupSocket() function. Seems that everything was getting triggered but on second connection, after disconnect, my server is refusing connection. Thanks a lot for your help in trying to figure this out.

Comment: And an update. I was trying to recreate the connection with socket.connect(), but I should have used the same object and call socket.socket.disconnect() as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598900/how-to-reconnect-after-you-called-disconnect . So the real problem had nothing to do with my question, my debugging should have been more thorough.